# Construct a continuous function with certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I need to construct a continuous function, $f(x)$, which is defined on $[0,\infty)$. The function need to satisfy several conditions:

1. $f(x)$ has two minimums at $x=0$ and $x=1$;
2. $\frac{f'(x)}{x}>0$ if $x>1$;
3. $\frac{f'(x)}{x}<0$ if $a<x<1$, where $a$ is between 0 and 1 ($0<a<1$);
4. $\frac{f'(x)}{x}>0$ if $x<a$;
5. $\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$.
6. $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}$ exist.

I think we need to construct a piecewise function. But I cannot find an example of such function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x^{2}(2a^{2}-x^{2})$ for $x <1$ and $f(x)=x-2+2a^{2}$ for $x \geq 1$ defines such a  function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.